# Any+time Datepicker

Tags: datetime, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/anytime.css" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#addsession").submit(function() {

                    $('.container_add_sesssion').show();

                    var answer=confirm ("are you sure you want to ADD this SESSION ?");             

                    if (answer) {   

                                // first hide any error messages

                                    $('.container_add_session').html("  processing please wait" );                                  
                                    $.post('add-session-process.php', $("#field1").serialize(), function(data) {
                                                                        $('#replace').hide();
                                                                        $('#replace').fadeIn(1500);
                                                                        $('#replace').html(data);
                                                                        $('#replace').append("<br>image goes here")

                                                                                                        });
                                                                            return false;
                }else{
                return false;
                }
                $('.container_add_session').hide();

             });
    });

    </script>

<style type="text/css">
 #field1 { color: #333333; background-image:url("clock.png");
    background-position:right center; background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #7f7f7f;font-weight:bold}
  #AnyTime--field1 {background-color:#EFEFEF;border:1px solid #CCC}
  #AnyTime--field1 * {font-weight:bold}
  #AnyTime--field1 .AnyTime-btn {background-color:#F9F9FC;
    border:1px solid #CCC;color: #333333}
  #AnyTime--field1 .AnyTime-cur-btn {color: red; background-color: #fcf9f6;
      border:1px solid #191919;}
  #AnyTime--field1 .AnyTime-focus-btn {border-style: inset}
  #AnyTime--field1 .AnyTime-lbl {color:black}
  #AnyTime--field1 .AnyTime-hdr {background-color: #ff6666; color:white}
  #field2 { color: #333333; background-image:url("clock.png");
    background-position:right center; background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #7f7f7f;font-weight:bold}
  #AnyTime--field2 {background-color:#EFEFEF;border:1px solid #CCC}
  #AnyTime--field2 * {font-weight:bold}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-btn {background-color:#F9F9FC;
    border:1px solid #CCC;color: #333333}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-cur-btn {color: red; background-color: #fcf9f6;
      border:1px solid #191919;}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-focus-btn {border-style: inset}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-lbl {color:black}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-hdr {background-color: #ff6666; color:white}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/anytime.js"></script>
  <h2>Dates and Sessions</h2>

<p class="details" >  

<?php 
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
// if edit get the showname form database, make ita session variableand echo it
if ($_SESSION['doevent']=='edit'){echo "Editing - ".$_SESSION['showname'];}

?>
</p>
  <div id="insidetabmain"><! start form area>

  <div id="insidetableft">
 <form id="addsession" action="">



    <dt id="event_date"><label for="event_date" class="required">Date and Time of session:</label></dt>

  <input type="text" id="field1" size="50"  value="" /><br/>
  <dt id="event_date"><label for="event_date" class="required">Doors Open:</label></dt>

  <dt><input type="text" id="field2" value="" /><br></dt>
  <dt><br><input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="add session" /><BR><BR></dt>

    </form>


<div class="container_add_session">
</div>

</div><!end leftbar>



    <div id="insidetableft"><!  second side bar>



    <div id="replace">
    This area will show dates as they are added:

    </div>


    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
      AnyTime.picker( "field1",
          { 

           ajaxOptions: { url:  "add-session-process.php"},

          format: " %Y ,%W, %M, %D,  Time : %H:%i ", firstDOW: 1 ,
          baseYear: 2011,
           latest: new Date(2014,11,31,23,59,59)

          } );

      $("#field2").AnyTime_picker(
          {
            ajaxOptions: { url: "add-session-process.php" },

           format: "%H:%i"

           } );
</script>
```

Comment: for some reason the message disapeared. I am trying to make all the data be sent via one ajax post call that serializes the data (see above). I can get seperate (get) posts, but have no data tranferedd via my standard ajax call . Why Not !!  how do I cope with seperate call in my PHP processing script.

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the wrong data in your `$.post()` function.

Try this:

```
$.post('add-session-process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){ 
  // rest of code to process AJAX response
});
```